# Using FFMPEG video convert, not play audio

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using this command its works fine, but remove audio of video file

```
ffmpeg -i background.jpg -i man-1.mp4 -filter_complex [1:v]chromakey=0x3BBD1E:0.1:0.2[ckout];[0:v][ckout]overlay[out] -map [out] box3.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the map.

```
ffmpeg -i background.jpg -i man-1.mp4 -filter_complex "[1:v]chromakey=0x3BBD1E:0.1:0.2[ckout];[0:v][ckout]overlay[o]" -map [o] -map 1:a box3.mp4
```

Comment: when i removed map, then video also not creating